# Android ui how to assign image buttons properly?

Tags: android, scaling, imagebutton

I am developing a application i am trying to assign image buttons properly but depending on screen they are changing i have added images of low density,high density and midium density images in low high and midium drawable folders.

here is my code and screen shot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
    android:paddingRight="20dip" >

<TableRow>       
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/aboutus"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:src="@drawable/aboutus"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       />
    <TextView
    android:text="About Us"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/services"         
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:src="@drawable/services123" />
    <TextView
    android:text="Services"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>    
    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/courses"           
       android:src="@drawable/services"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       />
    <TextView
    android:text="Courses"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">     
    <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/contactus"
       android:src="@drawable/services"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       />
       <TextView
    android:text="contact us"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
   </LinearLayout>
 </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
         <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/syllabus"
       android:src="@drawable/services"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       />
    <TextView
    android:text="Syllabus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">          
    <ImageButton 
       android:id="@+id/pingtoupdates"
       android:src="@drawable/services"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       />
    <TextView
    android:text="Ping To Updates"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="3dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two much of variations in layout_width and height from one table row item to the other. In some LinearLayout you have used fill_parent,fill_parent and in some wrap_content, wrap_content. First you need to correct this as you'r requirement says that each row items should be of same dimensions. 
 
For you case better approach would be to use a GridView. You just need to create one layout file(XML) for the row item and then you can use this for all the row items. 
Here is a sample code for grid item:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton 
           android:id="@+id/aboutus"
           android:src="@drawable/aboutus"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="2dp"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <TextView
           android:text="About Us"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:padding="3dip" 
           android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are new to GridView follow this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

After you are done with this then you should try multiple device support. 
You can follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for multiple device support.

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932951/how-to-show-an-image-proportional-to-the-screen/11933668#11933668) stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) would be the best as you can fix your layout there and specify the size of each image in the grid irrespective of their sizes.

Check this [sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) tutorial.

If you need more sample codes, you can find another nice tutorial on GridView [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) and [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) explains how to handle item selection from the grid, i.e. what happens when you click on any image on the grid.

Hope this helps!